# Optional ignored arguments in Ruby's nil#rationalize

Tags: ruby

I was perusing through the `NilClass` documentation, and I found a method `rationalize` that, when called on `nil`, "returns zero as a rational":

```
nil.rationalize
#=> 0/1
```

What's strange is that the documentation also states that "[The optional argument eps is always ignored](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-rationalize)".

Thus,

```
nil.rationalize(5)
#=> 0/1

nil.rationalize("monkey")
#=> 0/1

nil.rationalize(false)
#=> 0/1
```

What is the purpose of the `eps` argument, and why have an optional argument that is always ignored?

Comment: It's always ignored when the receiver is `nil`, but not always ignored in general. When the receiver is a float, for instance, it is used: http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-rationalize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `.rationalize` is also available on `Float`, `Integer`, `Complex` and `Rational`, the parameter is probably accepted for compatibility reasons. It might not be used for `NilClass`, but this way it's argument-compatible with the rest.

Comment: It looks like the eps is only used in the `Rational` and `Float` classes. I still don't understand the rationale behind the optional ignored argument because the implementation of `rationalize` is different for each class on which its defined. It's not inherited from `Numeric`.

Comment: @garythegoat For compatibility. The point of methods like `rationalize` is so that you can so `obj.rationalize` to convert whatever `obj` is to a rational without worrying about what `obj` is. If the `rationalize` signature is different for different classes then you're back to `is_a?` or arity checks before you call it. OTOH, `to_s` sometimes takes an argument and sometimes it doesn't, Ruby isn't exactly a paragon of consistency.

Comment: But it gives you the same result - a rational representation of the recipient. So it's a duck typing thing - no matter what kind of "number" you have, you can always call the same method with the same signature on it and get a rational back.

Comment: If Ruby had protocols (aka interfaces in Java), all of those would conform to the `Rationalizable` protocol, and they need to all conform to that.

Comment: @muistooshort `rationalize` is defined differently on different classes, so I'm still not sure why you'd have to resort to type checking with `is_a?` or arity checks if you left out the optional ignored arguments for `nil#rationalize`.

Comment: @garythegoat what do you mean by "defined differently"?

Comment: @janfoeh I mean that `rationalize` is implemented differently, in C, for each of the classes it is defined on. Since each implementation of `rationalize` is tailored for the class on which it is defined, I'm failing to understand why optional, ignored arguments are present for `nil#rationalize`.

Comment: Because of duck typing. It allows you to say "_you there, number! Whatever type you are, I need you as a rational number. If necessary (for example should you be a float), I am prepared to accept a wiggle room of Epsilon n to get the shortest possible representation. If not necessary, that's fine with me as well._" Otherwise, `i.rationalize(0.1)` would work fine on a Float, but give you an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`, only because you're calling it on an integer.

Comment: @janfoeh This makes sense to me now, and I'm not sure why it didn't before, as I'm familiar with the duck typing concept. Thanks & accepted

Comment: @janfoeh Also, it just occurred to me that calling methods on non-nil objects that are also defined on `nil` has potentially dangerous consequences. For example if you expected your output to be an instance of `Integer`, and you called `rationalize` on each instance, you may receive `0/1` as output when you call it on a `0` or on `nil`, which may cause bugs to lay undiscovered. In essence you will not receive the `NoMethodError` exception typical of calling methods on `nil`.

Comment: @garythegoat that's Ruby for you. Feel free to undefine the methods you disagree with ;)

Comment: @garythegoat You might want to look at `nil.to_i`, `nil.to_a`, `nil.to_h`, `nil.to_f`, ... This behavior is actually a feature so that you can hide noisy `nil` checks behind method calls that convert `nil` to whatever. If you need to check for "`nil` means error" then you do it explicitly. Every decision has tradeoffs.

Comment: @garythegoat If you need some safety with respect to possible `nil` values, `Float(nil)` (or `Integer(nil)`, `Rational(nil)` etc.) will raise an exception (unlike `to_f` and its ilk). `rationalize` can then be called on any valid results to get what you want without that particular worry.